# Returning / setting a value within a thread

Tags: c#, asp.net, multithreading

I'm trying to open an OpenFileDialog within C# (codebehind, on an asp.net page). Because the regular references and the system.windows.form ones have some conflicts, I'm having to use the OpenFileDialog box within a thread, as below:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Thread newThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(BrowseForFile));
    newThread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
    newThread.Start();     
}

static void BrowseForFile()
{
    System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog MyFile = new System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog();
    if (MyFile.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
    {

    }
}
```

The way the page works means that this has to be in C# - using asp.net's fileupload won't work.

Now, the OpenFileDialog appears fine, and I can get values from it, but I ideally need to pass values into the thread (the BrowseForFile) and have it work with other controls on the page, in order to set things up. However, I'm very new to using threads.

Can someone show me, basically, how to get an integer from the Button1_Click into the BrowseForFile, and how I would set a label on the page from BrowseForFile?

Comment: You cannot show UI on a server.  You need to use HTML.

Comment: Why is this tagged asp.net? Looks like windows forms to me?

Comment: This might *appear* to work while doing development because your server is the same computer that you are developing on, localhost, but using `System.Windows.Forms` in an ASP.NET application is almost always wrong.

Answer (score 0):

If you use a modern version of .net you could use async-await for this. This makes it much easier for you to communicate with your dialog and to pass data to the thread that performs your background work.

To be able to use async-await:

- Declare your function async
- Let your function return Task instead of void and Task`<TResult`> instead of TResult.

  - There is one exception: event handlers may return void
  - In your async function start your other threads using Task.Run
  - while the other thread is running you can do other things
  - if you need the result: call await Task.

In your case, you'll have to change your thread class into a procedure that contains the code in your thread class. This procedure may be in any class. It must be declared async and return Task instead of void:

Of course you'll have to change your thread class into an async procedure:

```
private async Task MyThreadProcedureAsync(string fileName)
{
    // do something really slow with fileName and return void
}



protected async void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string fileName = this.BrowseForFile();
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(fileName))
    {
        var myTask = Task.Run( () => MyThreadProcedureAsync(fileName))
        // if desired do other things.
        // before returning make sure the task is ready:
        await myTask;
        // during this wait the UI keeps responsive
    }
}

private string BrowseForFileName()
{
    using (var dlg = new System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog())
    {
        // if needed set some properties; show the dialog:
        var dlgResult = dlg.ShowDialog(this);
        if (dlgResult == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
        {
            return dlg.FileName;
        }
        else
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```